# calling msbuild in python script

Tags: python, visual-studio, msbuild, subprocess

Hi I would like to execute msbuild in python script

Since I don't run this in visual studio developer command prompt,
I run

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Then I do

```
  msbuild example.props
```

How can I run this in python?
I tried to do

```
 subprocess.call('\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\\vcvarsall.bat\"\n')
```

then call

```
 subprocess.call(['msbuild', filename]) # filename is string variable
```

but I get an error saying that it coudln't find the file specified..
I am pretty sure there should be a way to do this but I couldn't find how..
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Did it say which file couldn't be found?

Comment: It said it couldn't find 'msbuild'

Comment: There was no issue when you called the .bat file?  If not, it seems like your environment isn't being updated when you run the .bat file.  Try using the shell=True option for call and see if that changes things.

Comment: I went ahead and put this in an answer so other people may benefit.  Glad that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not using the `shell=True` option to `call`, each call is essentially isolated from each other.  Therefore, sourcing the .bat file has no effect on the second call.  Add `shell=True` on both calls so that the first call can effect the second call.

**Note**:  I only recommend `shell=True` here because it is obvious that this is only being run on one platform (Windows), so there will be no cross-platform issues.

Comment: Hi, sorry about bring this up, but for some reason, it's not working. I don't think it's properly shared between calls

Comment: I'm on Mac, so I can't see if this works on Windows, but instead of using subprocess.call, try using os.system.  This will completely bypass whatever walled garden subprocess.call creates.  I have verified that this works on my Mac (I also had troubles with shell=True).  It's not elegant, but it seems to work.